# Error 500 on trying connect to Jasperreports Server. Datasource

Tags: jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

I'm running into this error in Jaspersoft Studio:

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: status code: 500, reason phrase: 500
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.restv2.RESTv2ExceptionHandler.handleException(RESTv2ExceptionHandler.java:83)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.restv2.ARestV2ConnectionJersey.toObj(ARestV2ConnectionJersey.java:48)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.restv2.RestV2ConnectionJersey.addOrModifyResource(RestV2ConnectionJersey.java:649)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.ProxyConnection.addOrModifyResource(ProxyConnection.java:349)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.WSClientHelper.saveResource(WSClientHelper.java:313)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.WSClientHelper.saveResource(WSClientHelper.java:270)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.wizard.resource.ResourceWizard$1.run(ResourceWizard.java:85)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:434)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:352)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1034)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.wizard.resource.ResourceWizard.performFinish(ResourceWizard.java:77)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:833)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4054)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3642)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.action.resource.PropertiesAction.run(PropertiesAction.java:75)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.ServerProvider.doubleClick(ServerProvider.java:304)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.repository.RepositoryView$2$1.run(RepositoryView.java:126)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:132)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4029)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3645)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:643)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:550)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.rcp.intro.Application.start(Application.java:93)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
```

I created a new Data Adapter Connection, and a new JasperReports Server connection and it went well with testing. However, I have to edit/create the Data Sources but that's where I'm getting the error from when I click to "Finish".

How can I get around this?